# Jenkins plugin "Visual Studio Team Services Continuous Deployment" throws NullPointerException

Tags: jenkins, tfs

My system is an on-premises setup for TFS 2015 and I am trying to get Release Management working with my Jenkins continuous integration system. I have recently added the ""Visual Studio Team Services Continuous Deployment" [plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/vsts-cd-plugin)  to Jenkins. After finding out that I need to have Basic Authentication enabled on my TFS server to avoid a `401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.` error I am getting to the next error: `NullPointerException.`

I have looked through the code for the vsts-cd-plugin to see that there is an explicit reference to this API call that I don't believe is in TFS 2015 Update 3...

```
"/_apis/release/releases?api-version=3.0-preview.2"
```

Has anyone been successful in using the vsts-cd-plugin with Jenkins and an on-premises TFS 2015 setup?  Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can fix this problem to create a TFS Release from Jenkins?

Comment: @cece-msft, Were you able to setup the environment and test my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The API version 3.0-preview.2 is for Visual Studio Team Services, it is not included in On-premise TFS. In On-premise TFS, you need to use 2.2-preview.1.

> api-version = 3.0-preview.1
>
> Using on-premises: An earlier, and slightly different, version of this
>   Release Management API is available in Team Foundation Server 2015
>   Update 2. To use, you must specify an API version of 2.2-preview.1.
>
> New release references a release definition to deploy an application
>   comprising of one/

You can try to download the source code of the plugin and update the API version and then build it on your local machine and install it in Jenkins.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good long-term solution for me to be re-building the plugin and then probably have to continue modifying it every subsequent patch to the plugin.  Do you know if you can get the original authors to update the plugin to be more flexible with different installations of TFS?

Comment: @eph_tagh I don't know the author, sorry. :(